# Improve performance of RConnection and Rserve

Tags: r, linux, rserve

If we execute an R script directly in R prompt in Linux environment, it  takes around 30 mins to complete.

The same R script if we execute from java using RConnection, eval and Rserve for each line it takes thrice the time.
Basically the performance is very bad. And in most of the occasion it never ends up in result.

Can anyone please tell how to improve the performance using Rconnection.

Comment: Are both instances of R on the same machine? Is some time being spent processing the object by Java? At the moment, it's difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this issue got resolved.

Comment: Issue was we were using REXP ` rResponseObject = rConnection.parseAndEval("try(eval("+rCode+"),silent=TRUE)");
   if (rResponseObject.inherits("try-error")) 
   { 
    System.out.println("R Serve Eval Exception : "+rResponseObject.asString()); 
   }
   else
   {
     isCorpusCreated=true;
   }
   rResponseObject=null;`  As some of the object in R were occupying space of 3 to 4 GB especially matrix object. which was getting transferred into java environment and persisted in the object rResponsceObject. Hence it was slow.

Comment: now we started using ` rConnection.voidEval(rCode); `
which does not transfer the object back to java envrnoment which solved the issue.. Now it is taking the same amount of time as in the R envirnoment

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and accept it. It's recommended, even